# Windows 10 update assistant pop-up every few minutes

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

### The Situation

We use teamviewer to connect to small form-factor pc's in a factory. I check these every day, twice a day. I checked today and i noticed the below message.

[image]

I then clicked OK and thought nothing of it. I checked back about 10 minutes later and the message is back. I clicked OK again, checked back in 10 minutes, and to no surprise the message was back again.

### The Question

How can i stop this from popping up? I don't need these updates, and i can't install them anyway. The PC only has a 32GB ssd inside.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Update Assistant in Windows 10 cannot be uninstalled, but there might be
a way to get rid of it:

- From Start, start the *Task Scheduler*
- In the left Pane, navigate to: *Microsoft > Windows > UpdateOrchestrator*
- In the right pane, according to current Windows version, either double-click
  *Update Assistant* or click *Properties*
- Click on the *Triggers* Tab
- Double-click each of the triggers and uncheck "Enabled"
- Click OK

If you used *Update Assistant*, you need to do the same to the event
*Update Assistant CalendarRun*.

Restart to finish.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: Update: It has worked like a charm, thank you.